# Accidentally tried to flash rom after doing saferoot (not possible)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms, odin

I was referring to a guide on how to do a saferoot for Galaxy s3 (Verizon) and then switched over to a guide on how to flash a custom rom. Bad idea.

1. http://www.droidviews.com/root-verizon-galaxy-s3-android-4-3-vrucml1-firmware/
2. http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-siii/

I didn't realize that you can't install custom roms with the saferoot. You need to use the "SkipSoft's S3 Toolkit", mentioned in the second article, but I simply jumped to the rom manager section, thinking I was done with rooting my phone. So I used saferoot, and then went on to the other guide and proceeded to install rom manager, and installed clockworkmod flash recovery, and tried to "reboot in recovery".

Now after rebooting, it says "System software not authorized by Verizon Wireless has been found on your phone. Please turn off your phone and go to the nearest Verizon Wireless store for help."

What can I do? I want to install the cyanogen custom root, but somehow need to backtrack to root my phone the right way. Is this possible?

Comment: Galaxy s3 on 4.3 cannot do custom roms, because the bootloader is locked. Also, saferoot is the recommended root.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enter into recovery of download mode?

As your phone is booting up, (right after the phone vibrates), press and hold on Volume Up and Home to enter recovery. Volume Down and Home to enter Download.

If you can enter either of these, there may still be some hope by flashing back your stock Verizon rom through Odin.

Otherwise, you will need to send it in for servicing.